# Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using hibernate and spring and I am getting this exception upon executing the following code:

```
Session oSession = getSession();
     try
     {
         oSession.setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT);
         getHibernateTemplate().delete(oProject);
         oSession.flush();
         bResult = true;
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         bResult = false;
         logger.error(e);
     }
```

I've read some session management regarding hibernate and I have a hunch that this code has poor session handling. What could be the reason of having two open sessions? Hibernate APIs says that the `getSession()` function returns either a new session object or an existing. In this case, where does it get the existing session object? and if it creates a new session object would that still be fine to process the collection involved?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! more power stackoverflow.

Comment: You have omitted the most important part: what's actually behind that `getSession` call? On which object are you calling this? It looks like you are writing this code inside some framework. Hibernate's own method is `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - the getSession() call is from the HibernateDAOSupport of the spring framework. It looks like the class was extended and that function was used. Sorry for the lack of information.

Answer (score 4):

`HibernateTemplate.delete(Object entity)` will delete the object using other Session inside `HibernateTemplate` but you open a new `Session` object by your own, which is the root cause of the error. So you should try as following:

```
 try
 {
     getHibernateTemplate().delete(oProject);
     bResult = true;
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     bResult = false;
     logger.error(e);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate checks if there is a session already in opened for the current thread. If not, it creates a new one using the SessionFactory; otherwise it reuses the already opened session. Well you can reattach entity objects and the same goes for collections containing entity objects too.

But you have not mentioned how is Hibernate configured to handle sessions. It could be that you manually open sessions and the code you posted actually opens 2 sessions.